# SpringMVC randomly not returning a response

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, tomcat, spring-mvc, httpresponse

I've got a SpringMVC application that is randomly not returning a response to AJAX requests.  Or rather, it would appear that it is not returning the response.

In my Network graph (Chrome or Firefox), I see a GET request being made, and I see the full stack trace on the server side which is handling/responding to the request.  However, the browser never seems to receive a response to the request as the GET method never completes.

I am completely clueless as to how/where to start tracking this down.

I am running on Tomcat 7.0.42 and using AngularJS on the front side.  I have my firewall completely stopped, so I do not believe that it is related to blocked ports/communications.

Where/how can I validate that a response is being committed?  Furthermore, how can I isolate where this disconnection is occurring and why the browser isn't receiving any response?  I cannot seem to replicate this behaviour when I issue manual requests via Postman.

I am doing the dev work on OSX v10.7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow.  After several hours of trying to dig around and find the solution, I installed Wireshark and decided to look at actual packets.  Turns out I was getting double requests for a single get, but to 2 different ports.  After further inspection (checking to see what was listening on the port), I noticed that it was the Sophos Anti-Virus that was seemingly intercepting the request and not responding.

I'm still not sure quite how the AV intercepts the requests before passing them along, nor how it decides to abort a response, but turning off has made a world of difference.

Hopefully this learning experience will help someone else if they get stuck with something similar.

Comment: Just throwing it in here since I don't know Sophos AV :-) But isn't there a way in Sophos to whitelist the domain or requests? Just curious...

Comment: Yes - you can put in whitelists.  But it still sits in the middle of the connection.  Stopping it altogether reduces any risks of it interfering with my requests/responses.  Lesson well learned.

Answer (score 0):

SpringMVC is pretty rock solid and the only thing I can imagine is that your handler is not returning a response under certain instances.  Look in your code for conditionals or exception handlers that don't return a proper response.

Comment: I have tried to go through this with a fine tooth comb, but can't find anything.  It is driving me insane.  Additionally, it happens rather randomly; not a specific request is causing it, or in repeatable conditions, although it happens regularly.

Comment: I know how it is.  If you have some sort of complex processing going on after you return from your handler, then you can maybe blame that code, but if you are doing a straight forward response I can't image that there is a flaw in the basic spring mvc response mechanism.

Comment: Turns out I was chasing ghosts at the application level (which I somewhat expected, but needed to confirm).